# Retrieving more post from public fb page using FB graph api

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As i have tried getting the post from a public facebook page, by passing access token, however i can only retrieve the latest 25 post. Can i increase number number of post returned? or can i retrieve post based on dates i want. If possible, can someone guide me how to do so?

what i have now:

```
  static JsonObject GetPost(string accessToken)
    {
        FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

        JsonObject pagePost = facebookClient.Get("/pageName/posts") as JsonObject;

        return pagePost;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the pagination links in the API response? perhaps your SDK wraps those, but there should be a way to get the next page - you could also just ask for more in the initial request (e.g. `facebookClient.Get("/pageName/posts?limit=100")`)

Comment: what is **pageName**? sample ? get posts for a friend of my lists?